# TabLayout migration to AndroidX

Tags: java, android, androidx, android-tablayout, material-components

I've migrated my Android App into AndroidX using refactor->migrate to AndroidX.
Also fixed the ones that needed to be fixed manually. The only problem left is the `TabLayout`.

Previously, before AndroidX migration, I'm using this code:

```
    @Override
    public void setOnTabSelectedListener(OnTabSelectedListener onTabSelectedListener) {
        ......
        super.setOnTabSelectedListener(onTabSelectedListener);
    }

    @Override
    void selectTab(Tab tab) {
        ........
        super.selectTab(tab);
    }
```

But with AndroidX, when building I'm having this error: 
**method does not override or implement a method from a supertype**

and

**`selectTab(com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.Tab)` is not public. Cannot accessed from outside package..**

How can I correctly migrate this to AndroidX?

Edit:
forgot to mention that I have my own Tab class and I'm just extending the `TabLayout`. I've override the `selectTab` since I wan't to do something on it before calling the parent `selectTab()`. In AndroidX, the `selectTab` is not public anymore, so how can I override it to do something first?

Working code before AndroidX

```
@Override
void selectTab(Tab tab) {
   //if condition met, return;
  super.selectTab(tab);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`selectTab`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout#selecttab) method:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(index));
```

About the listener you can use the [`addOnTabSelectedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout#addOnTabSelectedListener(com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener))

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(OnTabSelectedListener);
```

If you are using a custom `TabLayout` just use:

```
@Override
public void selectTab(@Nullable Tab tab) {
    //your code....
    super.selectTab(tab);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Please see my edit for the selectTab problem.

Comment: @MarcQuebrarTan The method `selectTab` is public starting from the version 1.1.0.

Comment: Great! I was using 1.0.0. That is why. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First initialize TabLayout:

```
private TabLayout tabLayout;
```

Then in onCreate:

```
tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.your_tab_layout_id)
```

Then add listener like this:

```
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            //
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            //
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Please see my edit for the selectTab problem

Answer (score 0):

Isolved by changing `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` to `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'` in build.gradle app level.